# Given an integer $N$, determine the number of pairs $(A, B)$ such that: $1≤A,B≤N$ such that $A + B$ is odd.

Tags: linear-algebra

I was trying to solve this problem.

**Explanation:**
Test case 1: If $N=1$. There are no pairs satisfying the given conditions. *($0$ pairs)*

Test case 2: If $N=2$. The pairs satisfying both conditions are: $(1, 2)$ and $(2, 1)$. *($2$ pairs)*

Test case 3: If $N=3$. The pairs satisfying both conditions are: $(1, 2)$, $(2, 1)$, $(2, 3)$ and $(3, 2)$. *(4 pairs)*

How is the solution to this problem equivalent to $\lfloor \frac{N^2}{2}\rfloor$

For e.g.
If $N=3$

$(3^2)/2 = 4.5$

Floor value of $4.5 = 4$

Comment: How many even numbers can you choose? How many odd?

Comment: From [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question): "Your question should be clear without the title. After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. **The title is not the first sentence of your question**, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title."

Answer (score 1):

There are $\lceil{N/2\rceil}$ odd numbers, $\lfloor{N/2\rfloor}$ even, so there are $2\lceil{N/2\rceil}\lfloor{N/2\rfloor}$ such pairs.